# The proof of convergence of $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} {1\over {k^p}} $

Tags: integration

Using  the  estimate  $${1\over {k^p}}\lt \int_{k-1}^k {{dx}\over {x^p}}$$  I  get $${\sum_{k=1}^{n}} {{1}\over {k^p}} \lt \int_1^n {{dx}\over {x^p}}$$ Now  convergence  is  proved  if  the  integral  on  the  right  side   converges.  How to  prove  that  $?$

Comment: It converges provided $p>1$, as you can find out by explicit integration.

Comment: Try evaluating the integral. You should know the antiderivative of $\frac 1{x^p}$.

Comment: Technically, it is less than 1+ $\int_1^{n}\frac{dx}{x^p}$. Note what happens to the integral on the right when $k=1$ - it becomes undefined:  $$\frac{1}{1^p}<\int_{0}^1\frac{dx}{x^p}=+\infty$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HINT:

$$\int_1^n\frac{1}{x^p}\,dx=\begin{cases}\frac{1}{1-p}\left(\frac{1}{n^{p-1}}-1\right)&,p\ne 1\\\\\log n&,p=1\end{cases}$$

Comment: So  with  $n\rightarrow \infty $ and  $p\gt 1$  we  have ${1\over {p-1}}$ . So the  series  converges.

Comment: Yes; well done!

Answer (score 2):

You may observe that, if $p \neq1$,
$$
\int_1^n {{dx}\over {x^p}}=\left[ \frac{x^{-p+1}}{-p+1}\right]_1^n=\ldots
$$
Can you take it from here?